# Как увеличить область клика для взаимодействия input`a

Tags: html, css

Есть элемент input:
[image: input]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.bar {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
  left: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
    
}

input {
  border: hidden;
  width: 85%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
       
        <input type="text" style="border:none;">

            
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Но кликнуть на него я могу только с половины поля. Как это исправить?

Comment: Что значит "только с половины поля"? Чего Вы добиваетесь?

Comment: @IgorR. я могу кликнуть на инпут только по середине поля ни левее ни правее он кликам не поддаётся

Answer (score 1):

1. Замени div на label.
2. Всё равно это плохая идея, потому что клик правой кнопкой будет отличаться.

```css
.bar {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
  left: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

input {
  border: hidden;
  width: 85%;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<label class="bar">
  <input type="text" style="border:none;">
</label>
```

Comment: не работает(( теперь можно и с верхнего края нажать но в правом центре также нельзя

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сделать так:

```css
input {
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 25px 0 50px;
  
  display: block;
  margin: calc(50vh - 25px) auto 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```